# Count the exact number of children with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Im trying to find count the exact number of a child and then add a class to another element matching that class, in this example the parent (it wont be the direct parent where I'm trying to achieve this).

```js
$(".test").each(function(index, elem) {
  var countchild = $(this).find(".child");
  if (countchild.length > 4) {
    $(".test").addClass("four")
  } else {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you could store the appropriate class names in an array. You can then access the right class by its index based on the number of found children, something like this:

```js
var classArr = ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz'];

$(".test").each(function(index, elem) {
  $(this).addClass(classArr[$(this).find('.child').length - 1]);
});
```

```css
.bar { color: #0C0; }
.buzz { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm this seems exactly what im after. It wont work for me though - it works when I set the count to 0 for some reason. Seems like an error on my side, the answer is correct-

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.test').find('.child').length;
```

On the basic of child count you can add class like:

```
var arr = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
var count = $('.test').find('.child').length;
$('.test').addClass('one');
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2tgdbgc3/1/)

Comment: How do I count them though? I want a specific class if the count is one, or two, or three, etc.. I dont want to add any new classes to the children.

Comment: I still dont understand how to reach for a specific number of childrens? not sure you understood my question? I want to give, in this case, the parent a class based on the amount of children. If there are three children, add a class to the parent, like .three. If its four children, give the parent class of .four, etc.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try this :

```
 var countchild = $(".test > .child");
 if (countchild.length > 4) {
    $(".test").addClass("four")
  } else {
  }
```

FYI,

`.test > .child` will only select child that are direct children to test (that is, there are no other elements in between).

`.test  .child` will select any child that are inside test, even if there are other elements between them.